# Circuit Breaker Upgrade Complications

Tags: electrical, circuit-breaker

I'm currently renting a unit in a commercial warehouse complex. Each unit has individual MLO panels inside the unit, and then a large split meter base with individual breakers for each unit in a centralized location in a separate part of the complex.

We're trying to upgrade the that main breaker for our unit from 100A to 125A if we have to, but preferably 150A.

So the problem we're having is that the breaker in the centralized area is a Cutler Hammer QC2100, and is part of their QuickLag series, which only seems to go up to 100A. It's a cable in/cable out breaker and it connects to https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Circuit-Breakers-Cable-In-Out-Base-Mounting-Clips/Eaton/QC6BP/product.aspx?zpid=61066
instead of something like a DIN rail or a simple bolt on. The clips are attached to the enclosure, and the breakers for everyone else's units are just kinda in a row on their own separate set of clips.

Does anyone know if there's a similar style of breaker that will fit on those clips and has a higher ampacity rating? Can I remove the clips and switch to a bolt on style breaker, or install a short DIN rail and attach to that? I'm trying to avoid having to change out the entire meetering enclosure cause I'd be paying to modify 16 other tenants systems and that gets a little pricy.

my electrician and several supply houses in the area don't seem to know if there's a way to do it without upgrading the service for the entire complex, so I figured I'd ask here.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: The Electrician and electrical supply shop don't know, so you thought you'd ask a bunch of chumps on the internet?

Comment: I'll upgrade the whole service if I need too and the electrician knows it. I get the feeling they're waiting me to foot a much larger bill. The supply houses didn't seem to have any idea what I was asking. So yes, I'm asking elsewhere.

Comment: Some photos might be helpful.

Comment: Got it. Here's a link to the actual breaker, and a picture of it in its enclosure. https://www.platt.com/platt-electric-supply/Circuit-Breakers-Cable-In-Out-2-Pole-Breakers/Eaton/QC2100/product.aspx?zpid=60887   http://imgur.com/G2TGriG

Comment: It is highly unlikely that you will be able to upgrade the breaker to 150A. Typically 100 to 150A is a different footprint/mount. Is the upgrade from 100A to 125A really necessary? As in worth the cost of replacing the cable/conduit?? I highly doubt it. IMO an upgrade to less than 200A is rather silly. The cost difference in material between 150A and 200A is negligible, and the labor is basically the same.

Comment: @SpeedyPetey There are no QC (or any other QUICKLAG family) type breakers in >125A in *any* footprint...

Answer (score 1):

Even if the 150A breaker existed (and it seems like it doesn't), that's unfortunately just the start. You would almost certainly need to upgrade the conductors to and from the 150A breakers for the higher ampacity, and quite possibly the conduit in which they travel as well, which would involve significant expense. And then the main panel to which they connect may not be rated for more than 100A per meter anyway.

So I'm guessing your decision is likely to be upgrade everyone to 200A potential or nothing.

I'd be curious how this actually turned out...